# How to set up multiple accounts in a single Google Talk installation?

Tags: windows-7, google-talk

I would like to have multiple accounts logged in Google Talk for Windows (poligamy).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/975/google-talk-run-multiple-instances-or-login-as-multiple-users/

I discovered that the `/nomutex` command line argument can enable multiple concurrent instances of Google Talk.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to auto-login in both accounts, here is the procedure:

> 1. Download script [gtalk_save_config.txt](https://sites.google.com/site/metattech/attachments/gtalk_save_config.txt?attredirects=0&d=1) and rename it into gtalk_save_config.bat
> 2. Download script [gtalk_launch_both.txt](https://sites.google.com/site/metattech/attachments/gtalk_launch_both.txt?attredirects=0&d=1) and rename it into gtalk_launch_both.bat
> 3. Login into Google Talk client under account 1
> 4. Run script "gtalk_save_config.bat"
> 5. Logout and login into Google Talk client under account 2
> 6. Edit "gtalk_save_config.bat" and change GTALK_ACCOUNT_INDEX from 1 to 2
> 7. Run script "gtalk_save_config.bat"
>
> Each time that you want to start the 2 instances of GTtalk, run the script "gtalk_launch_both.bat".
>
> Note : the "save" script must be re-run each time that you change settings in the Google Talk client (change password, ...)
>
> Note : the script can also be used to automate switching of other settings, for instance HTTP proxy settings, if you replace "Accounts" by "Options" in the registry path.

Source: [Launching 2 Google Talk instances under 2 separate accounts](http://meta-tech.blogspot.com/2012/08/launching-2-google-talk-instances-under.html)